# How can I print on a new line every single time

Tags: python, newline

```
var5 = "27"
var6 = "99"

print(10 * str(int(var5) + int(var6)\n))
```

**Error:**

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Comment: print() adds a new line by default

Comment: `print` will add a newline on its own. If you really want to add an extra one, you need to fix your parentheses and append the *string* `"\n"`.

Comment: It looks like you have `\n` at the end of your expression: `int(var5) + int(var6)`. This is a syntax error. Remove this and all will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print automatically adds a new line so you can just use:

```
var5 = "27"
var6 = "99"
for i in range(10):
    print(str(int(var5) + int(var6)))
```

in your case, you need to put \n in quotes:

```
var5 = "27"
var6 = "99"

print(10 * (str(int(var5) + int(var6)) + '\n'))
```

also, you should set your variables to integers to optimize your code and make it more readable:

```
var5 = 27
var6 = 99

print(10 * (str(var5 + var6) + '\n'))
```

or

```
var5 = 27
var6 = 99
for i in range(10):
    print(str(var5 + var6))
```

Hope this helped! ^^